# How to create win/lose counter updating numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Essentially what I am trying to do is create a numpy array based on if else conditions that determines the outcome of win, lose, or tie and will update array like so:

Example:

```
array(['lose','lose','tie','tie','win','tie'])
```

Would produce numpy array:

```
[-1,-2,-2,-2,-1,-1]
```

Where `lose = -1`, `win = +1`, and `tie = 0` (do nothing)

I have tried a few things such as `np.count_nonzero(conditions)` but cannot quite figure this out. Can anyone help?

```
def game_session(num_games=100):
values = rand.randint(1,7, 2*num_games)
rolls_array = values.reshape((num_games,2))
for i in rolls_array:
    sum2 = i[0]+i[1] 

    if np.count_nonzero(sum2 ==2 or sum2==3 or sum2==12): #lose


    elif  np.count_nonzero(sum2 ==7 or sum2==11): #win


    elif np.count_nonzero(sum2 == 1 or sum2 == 4 or sum2 == 5 or sum2 == 6 or sum2 == 8 or sum2 == 9 or sum2 == 10): #do nothing
```

Comment: Hello welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please paste a sample of the code you have tried?

Comment: Are you looking for `np.cumsum([lose,lose,tie,tie,win,tie])`?

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question with code. The only reason I didn't before was because i don't really have anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use np.where with cumsum. [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html?highlight=where#numpy-where) (cond[, x, y]) returns element from x and y based on condition. Since there are three strings to be mapped, this code uses a nest np.where

```
result = np.cumsum(np.where(a == 'lose', -1, np.where(a == 'win', 1, 0)))

array([-1, -2, -2, -2, -1, -1])
```

You can also use np.vectorize,

```
d = {'win':1, 'lose':-1, 'tie':0}
np.cumsum(np.vectorize(d.get)(a))
```

Comment: might be useful to explain the nested `np.where()` as Forextrader is a new user.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using `map` and `reduce`:

```
resp = list(functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + [x[-1] + y], 
            map(mapper, arr), 
            [0]))
resp.pop(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, just for fun, I wanted to see if I could achieve this only with list comprehension (so this could work on a simple list too). Behold the result :

```
>> x = ["win","lose","win","win","tie","tie","lose"]
>> results = [[sum([1 if it=="win" else 0 if it=="tie" else -1 for i,it in enumerate(x)][:y])
      if y > 0 else 0][0] + [1 if it=="win" else 0 if it=="tie" else -1][0] for y,it in enumerate(x)]
>> results
output : [1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1]
```

This was fun to do, any ideas on how to optimize this?

Answer (score 0):

A shorter alternative:

```
np.cumsum(1*(x=='win')-(x=='lose'))
```

Output:

```
array([-1, -2, -2, -2, -1, -1])
```